# Link Specific Redirection Script

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, redirect

I have a below script, is it possible to add link specific redirect like:

- `www.Link1.com/abc/ced` : `www.redirect.com/www.Link1.com/abc/ced`
- `www.Link2.com/z/x` : `www.linkme.com/www.Link2.com/z/x`

I tried adding variables but unable to add subfolders in the link url to the redirect.

```
<a href="http://link1.com">link 1</a>
<a href="http://link2.com/alsoredirected">link 2</a>
<a href="http://wikipedia.org">not redirected</a>
```

```
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var redirects = {
    "http://link1.com": "http://google.com",
    "link2.com": "http://google.com"
};

for(var i = 0;i < aTags.length; i++) {
    var url = aTags[i].getAttribute("href");

    for (var redirect in redirects) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(redirect);

        if (pattern.test(url)) {
            aTags[i].setAttribute("href", redirects[redirect]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any errors which you can display? Maybe make a jsfiddle from it for quick testing because there is no reason a redirect would refuse to use subfolders

Comment: Your real links probably contain characters that need to be escaped in a regex, like "."

Comment: I am trying to redirect "http://www.google.com/gmail" to "www.redirectwebsite.com/redirect&uid=1?http://www.google.com/gmail"

Comment: the above code works very well if I need to just redirect the main domain to another main domain TLD. But when subfolders come into picture it does not work

Comment: I tried string replace, but it's not making any sense. Also To redirect all pages (wildcard) on main domain to another domain I used */* but it's only going to top level domain. If I have 20+ links to various pages on my site I want them to be redirected like www.redirectwebsite.com/redirect&uid=1?google.com/gmail and go to the same page. It's just that I want to this string www.redirectwebsite.com/redirect&uid=2? to each link with a specific uid number

Comment: I just need to add subfolders on both sides.